# Does the RODE Lav mic need a pre-amp?

Tags: audio-recording, audio, lavalier, rode, purchase-advice

I am looking for an inexpensive solution for youtube commentary videos. I came down to the RODE Lavalier, and the RODE SmartLAV+.

I don't have an iPhone, so I discovered that you can use any smartphone app to record the SmartLAV+ audio.

The question I have is: Can the regular RODE Lavalier mic also record directly into a smartphone or laptop, or is that some special feature of the SmartLAV+?

The RODE lavalier appears to have a slightly larger range than the SmartLAV+, and I like the idea of being able to change the connector as I get a bit better at sound and grow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the Lavalier can go to directly into a smartphone, just make sure you purchase the Micon11 connector together with the Lav. The Lavalier needs one of the "Micon" connectors to work anyway, it's a modular system that allows you to use the Lavalier with a whole range of devices, from 3.5mm minijack, XLR, smartphones (TRRS) or various brands of wireless systems.